# I am trying to read several csv files in python 2.7 and assign to a list variable

Tags: python, list, csv

I know this has been asked many times, but when I try this, I always get a list of lists.

The data in my input file (col.csv) looks like: 
`1,2,"black", "orange"`

There are NO hard returns in the data (`\n`)(it's a csv file, right?). When I use the csv module in python to import to a list using reader, I end up with list of lists, with the first entry, `list [0][0]` containing all the data.

How do I import the data into a list such that each comma separated value is a single list entry? The typical method I see uses `for row in...`, but I don't have rows – there are no returns in the data. Sorry for such a rank amateur question.

Comment: You can surround text with backquotes \`like this\` to make it look `like this`.

Comment: You mean the file consists of only one line?

Comment: Add your code, please

Comment: yes. file is one line of values, separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful for you to add your code, so we can know what you're doing wrong, but this should also work:

```
import csv
def getFirstCSVLine(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return next(csv.reader(f), None)
```

Comment: This is frustrating. I haven't submitted my files as they are large. One csv file is a list of population data–numbers separated by commas, no hard returns. Another file is a list of colors, surrounded by single quotes, and separated by commas. My problem isn't the input files. My problem is I want to import the data into list variables that look like this: pop = [123, 456,222]. Instead, I am getting data that looks like pop = [[123,[456],[222]]. The code I use to read from the file is: 
with open('pop.csv', 'rb') as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f)
     pop = list(reader)
     print (pop)

Comment: We need a sample of your data and the code you're trying now. Most good questions involve a [MCVE](/help/mcve). We can't do anything if we don't know exactly what your data looks like. If you can't reproduce the problem, then that's a problem we can't help with.

Comment: OK, I think I have kind of answered my own question. The problem I have been having is that when I say "comma separated value" (csv), I mean each element of the list is separated by a comma. Because of that belief, I created files that literally values separated with commas, and containing no hard returns (\n or \r etc). What most people seem to refer to as a csv file isn't. For example they may have a file that looks like this:
Thing1
Thing2

Answer (score 0):

OK, I should close this. My comment resolved the question above. I  reformatted my input csv files to be values, each on a separate "line", I was able to read the lines in one by one and append them to a list. This seems really sloppy and wasteful. I was hoping for a method to read a csv file and in one line assign it to a single list – not a list of lists, a single list.